# Time and datetime format with Informix and .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, informix

I have a table which has `starttime` field.this field of type `DateTime` and I configure it to `(Hour to Minute) in Specials`, because I wanna to store only time in this format.

ex:`10:45`

Now in my code :
I have the following problem:

```
 prd.StartTime = DateTime.Parse(record[1]);//.ToString("H:m"));


After Tracing: `StartTime = 6/22/2011 10:45:00 AM`
```

When I insert a record in this table, I get the following exception:

```
IBM.Data.Informix.IfxException: ERROR [22008] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]
Non-numeric character in datetime or interval.
```

**EDIT:**
When I make `default value` enabled to this field and try to insert without `starttime`, and select the value I found it was `17:48`, and when I change the Special to `Year` again the default value is `2011-06-22 17:48:00`.

---

**EDIT2:**

I make `StartTime` property as `string` rather than `DateTime`, and succeed to insert. Does this affect the validity of this field later.

Comment: I don't think this line of code is where your problem is.  All you are doing is setting the variable startTime to today's date at 10:45 A.M.  How are you actually inserting the data into your database?

Comment: yeah but this field in the database of type `DateTime`.but i specify in `Special` feature to be (`Hour To Minute`) just this part.

Comment: can you say what is the value of `record[1]`?

Comment: then i wanna to store it as a time

Comment: because if i make it of type `varchar` ,  if i make operations on it,it will considered as string and i will get wrong data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse("10:45")` is perfectly valid. However, it will produce an instance of `DateTime` containing today's date together with the time that you have parsed.

But the error you're getting is probably caused by the fact that the database you're using wants to store the date as a number.

Comment: `Informix` database, type of this field is `DateTime`,`Special` configuration is `Hour to  Minute`.

Comment: The thing is that the database is almost certainly storing the date as a number internally. You need to figure out what you need to convert it to before you send it through to the database. Read up on the Informix .Net Provider.

Comment: If the column is DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE, you must either (arrange for the C# database interface to) send a properly structured DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE structure to the server, or you must arrange for a properly formatted string to be sent.  And properly formatted means `"10:45"` without any extra characters.  I'm not sure how you do that - but it is the result you must achieve.  The alternative would be to use `EXTEND(?, HOUR TO MINUTE)` in the SQL statement, where your full timestamp value would be accepted by the date portion and the seconds would be chopped off by the 'EXTEND' operation.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("10:45");
```

its working for me, I think you need to check what is the value stored in record[1]

Answer (score 2):

I think this help you:

```
prd.StartTime = DateTime.Parse(record[1].ToString());
```